# Numpy Array to A Weather Map

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have some `numpy` array data like this below.

```
 Layer 1     Layer 2    LATITUDE     LONGITUDE
1.7964935   3.592987    24.813797   -88.901495
1.6611315   3.322263    24.6915     -87.84013
1.4888205   2.977641    24.694245   -87.868856
4.7826225   9.565245    29.965457   -87.565512
2.303408    4.606816    26.119643   -88.410623
3.7254165   7.450833    29.968328   -87.596143
```

I want to convert this `numpy` array into a weather map. I already have a basemap ready via matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.switch_backend('agg')
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np


#Lambert Conformal map of USA lower 48 states
plt.figure(figsize=(125,100))
m=Basemap ( llcrnrlon = -119 ,
llcrnrlat =22 ,
urcrnrlon = -64 ,
urcrnrlat =49 ,
projection = 'lcc' ,
lat_1 =33 ,
lat_2 =45 ,
lon_0 = -95 ,
resolution = 'h' ,
area_thresh =10000)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth = 3, color = 'white')
m.drawcountries(linewidth =3, color = 'white')
m.drawstates(linewidth = 2, color = 'white')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='black')
plt.title('MAP', fontsize=200)
plt.suptitle('TEMPERATURES', fontsize=50) # Add the text/suptitle to figure

plt.show()
plt.savefig('pic')
```

"I want to import my numpy data into this basemap as a rasterized map like this one"

[Example Weather map From Numpy array to Matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYzLg.png)

The code they used is here below. Note, my data is NOT a NetCDFFile. I have a `numpy` array.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm
#requires netcdf4-python (netcdf4-python.googlecode.com)
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plot rainfall from NWS using special precipitation
#colormap used by the NWS, and included in basemap.

nc = NetCDFFile('../../../examples/nws_precip_conus_20061222.nc')
#data from http://water.weather.gov/precip/
prcpvar = nc.variables['amountofprecip']
data = 0.01*prcpvar[:]
latcorners = nc.variables['lat'][:]
loncorners = -nc.variables['lon'][:]
lon_0 = -nc.variables['true_lon'].getValue()
lat_0 = nc.variables['true_lat'].getValue()
#create figure and axes instances
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
#create polar stereographic Basemap instance.
m =Basemap(projection='stere',lon_0=lon_0,lat_0=90.,lat_ts=lat_0,\
            llcrnrlat=latcorners[0],urcrnrlat=latcorners[2],\
            llcrnrlon=loncorners[0],urcrnrlon=loncorners[2],\
             rsphere=6371200.,resolution='l',area_thresh=10000)
#draw coastlines, state and country boundaries, edge of map.
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()
#draw parallels.
parallels = np.arange(0.,90,10.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10)
#draw meridians
meridians = np.arange(180.,360.,10.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10)
ny = data.shape[0]; nx = data.shape[1]
lons, lats = m.makegrid(nx, ny) # get lat/lons of ny by nx evenly space grid.
x, y = m(lons, lats) # compute map proj coordinates.
#draw filled contours.
clevs = [0,1,2.5,5,7.5,10,15,20,30,40,50,70,100,150,200,250,300,400,500,600,750]
cs = m.contourf(x,y,data,clevs,cmap=cm.s3pcpn)
#add colorbar.
cbar = m.colorbar(cs,location='bottom',pad="5%")
cbar.set_label('mm')
#add title
plt.title(prcpvar.long_name+' for period ending '+prcpvar.dateofdata)
plt.show()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is not so much of a difference between using a netcdf file or a numpy array. Of course the numpy array is much more directly applicable which makes this easier. The main difference here is rather that in the code you quote they have data lying on a regular grid, but your data seems totally arbitrary. You may either plot a `tricontourf` with those data, or you need to interpolate them on a regular grid first before drawing the contour.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thats a good idea using the tricontoutf function. Since I have exported my numpy array as output = np.compress(map(pointInBox,output),output,axis=0), how would I import this into matplot basemap and draw this data?

Comment: The only place where Basemap comes into play is `x, y = m(lons, lats)`. But I fear Basemap does not have a `tricontourf` function; instead you need to use the [`tri=True` argument of basemap's `contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.contourf) function.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest so if would be like this: np.savetxt(f, Data.npy)
 then contourf(x, y, Data.npy, *args, **kwargs) ?

Comment: It would be `contourf(x,y,z, tri=True)` where x,y,z are some numpy arrays.